# Loss of line breaks after interference with usual mode of creating or viewing content in drupal

Tags: drupal, newline, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

have created a module and two custom content types(protocol and protocol2). The module interferes with the usual mode of creating and editing the content type protocol and it changes the usual mode of viewing the content type protocol2.

In both these cases I get the problem that I lose the line breaks that where present in the textarea where the content was added, or in the case of viewing the line breaks that where stored.

That is a text entered in a textarea like this:

"Text

with

line

breaks."

ends up looking like this:

"Text with line breaks."

I have echoed the content of form_state and in both those cases I see no line breaks, and I use form_state when fetching and changing the text.

I'm not sure what the problem might be or exactly when and how that information is lost. Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: use nl2br() for printing such content

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that your default text format is one that strips line breaks.  Go to admin/config/content/formats to see your text formats and which one is the default.

If you want to specifically set a certain text format for your textarea in your custom module, you something like the below:

```
$form['yourfield'] = array(
 '#type'=>'text_format',
 '#format'=>'full_html',
 ...
 ...
);
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: It seems to keep it as "\n" so I used the function nl2br() to regain the linebreaks when viewing. I don't think it's a problem with the text format because it works fine if I disable mymodule_node_view which alters the how the view will look when viewed by setting "$node->content['body'][0]['#markup']"